# Source Transformation

Tags: dc, analysis, source

Ok, I have modified my question again about the same circuit seen below:
[image]

I have to simplify the circuit using source transformation and then find the current ix.

[image]
[image]

I have attached my attempted solutions but I do not get the correct answer of ix = 0.9A ( I am getting 4.3 amps now).

What I suppose I would like to know is:

Is my circuit simplification correct or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Or could I have solved the current ix easily from any of the earlier steps I made in my circuit simplification? i.e. when would you guys stop performing source transformation and circuit simplification and start with circuit analysis to solve the current ix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The far right is a voltage source with series resistance - it can be transformed, then combined with 9A.  Then you can transform back into voltage.

2) Now you have only a single loop equation.

Comment: I have modified my original post with a new question if you would like to see it.

Comment: From the first (hand drawn) circuit to the second, make sure you keep track of where ix is defined...

Comment: Will check that tomorrow. I kind of ignored the ix current as I assumed I would end up with a series circuit where ix = i total

Comment: Nope.  At the top, you have i_total = ix+9A.  At the bottom, you have i_total = ix.

Comment: Yeah I see how that could cause a problem. I think my circuit simplification is correct so will check the ix labelling and write back tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: Still having trouble with this question, can any one confirm that that the answer ix = 0.9A is correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, 0.9A is correct (confirmed in LTspice)

Comment: I have modified my original question (see above)

Comment: @David777 Your ix-9 should be ix+9

Comment: @ Selvek Ah what a silly mistake I was making! Need to be more careful with my current labelling. I now get ix = 0.9A, thank you so much. How do you rate others posts in this forum?